# Run Time Error in a C++ code

Tags: c++, c++11

I am getting Run-Time-Error in a C++ code. I am giving my source code error message. Need Help! Thanks in advance.

Source code:

```
#include <map>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

class Pair{
    public:
    int x;
    int y;
};

map < Pair , int > mapper;

int main(){
    Pair a;
    a.x = 8;
    a.y = 9;
    mapper[a] = 1; // Here i get Run-Time-Error
    return 0;
}
```

Error Message:

```
c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|237|note:   'const Pair' is not derived from 'const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>'|
```

Comment: Please post the error message verbatim in your question.

Comment: Sir already posted the error message

Comment: `Pair` is not *less-than* comparable

Comment: That's not a runtime error...

Comment: The compiler must take part of the blame; given that the lack of `operator<` is the problem, that's a very uninformative error message.

Comment: If you scroll up a bit, the first message should be "error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const
Pair' and 'const Pair')", which is slightly more informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you have to define a method to provide an ordering between Pairs.
map does not know how to compare the objects.

An Example:

```
#include <map>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

class Pair{
public:
  int x;
  int y;
};

bool operator<(const Pair& l, const Pair& r) {
  return l.x < r.x;
}


map < Pair , int > mapper;

int main(){
  Pair a;
  a.x = 8;
  a.y = 9;
  mapper[a] = 1;
  return 0;
}
```

In this example the Pairs are compared using the value of x, but you can provide a function based on what you want.

Comment: `mapper[a] = 1;` inserts element as well. and why does your `operator<` return `int` ?

Comment: @Pior S. Yes, I linked the discussion because the two operators have a different behaviour. But in general `insert` could be more efficient

Comment: @PiotrS. you are right, is off topic. Fixed. Thanks.